# Android CATEGORY HOME on 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am developing an App with CATEGORY HOME in the Manifest.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
```

It worked just fine with Android 4.1.1 but few days ago, I've upgraded to 4.1.2 and now the CATEGORY HOME doesn't work.

Do you know if this feature is deprecated with 4.1.2, or the problem lies on my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the following line of code for it to work

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Comment: 10x for the Answer! I've added also the LAUNCHER category. The app works now just fine even with API 4.2.2!